# mongoid: how to store an encrypted BSON::Binary field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, bson, attr-encrypted

I started using mongodb in my application and I'm now looking for an easy way to encrypt some sensitive binary data and store it in the mongodb.
When I do it for my MySql DB I use the `attr_encrypted`, but I guess that with mongoid, I'll need some other gem or method to do it, especially with a non-string field (BSON::Binary ).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted) works with Mongoid/other DataMappers. it is similar to how you use it with SQL.

Otherwise, you can always check out the [rails library](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html) for basic Encryption.

But, if you're looking for a specific gem that works with mongoid, you can go with either of these two options - (I have not included old/inactive gems but you can check out a complete list [here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/encryption))

[symmetric-encryption](https://github.com/reidmorrison/symmetric-encryption)

Here's a [how-to blog](https://www.compose.io/articles/encrypting-sensitive-data-in-your-mongodb-database/).
This one isn't Mongoid specific though.

The second option is [mongoid-encrypted-fields](https://github.com/KoanHealth/mongoid-encrypted-fields)
It is mongoid specific, albeit a little less popular. More info [here](http://jerryclinesmith.me/blog/2013/03/29/storing-encrypted-data-in-mongodb).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @benams For fields other than strings, you will have to use marshalling. See https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted#marshaling and http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Marshal.html.
This might be useful too http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2014/01/ruby-rails-objects-serialization-marshal-mongoid-and-performance-matters/